# Probability density function of a particle for computation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics

I'm writing a program, part of which relies on a particle being able to change location similar to a how a real particle would behave (pardon my physics).

For example, on a grid of 100x100, a particle at (0,0), at the next time step will most likely end up somewhere in it's immediate neighbourhood (or remain where it is). It still, however, has a non-zero probability of ending up at (100, 100)

Currently, I'm using the following probability density function (modified Gaussian). https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6eeryw1wj7

$$\frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{\left(-\frac{\left(x^{0.05}-b\right)^2}{2c^2}\right)}$$

But, this does not seem good enough to me.

Are there better probability density functions to approximate how a real particle behaves?

(once again, please pardon my physics)

**EDIT:**
A better formulation of my question could be this:

There's a particle that we observe at $(x,y)$.
We let the particle then enter a superposition.
What is the probability density function of finding the particle at $(x + dx, y + dy)$ when we observe the particle for a second time?

Comment: This is unanswerable unless you tell us what physical situation the particle is in. Is it a free particle or are there forces acting on it and is it confined to a $100\times 100$-box or is the grid periodic?

Comment: It is a free particle at rest confined to the 100x100 box.

Comment: Better yet, it is a wave (has not yet been observed), what are the chances of finding it from the coordinate it was observed at last.

Comment: Um, that's not how quantum physics works, at all (quantum objects simply are neither particles nor waves, all the time). [Wikipedia has the solution for the stationary states in abox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Higher-dimensional_boxes) but you can't "simulate" a quantum particle like that, it's not an object that moves around in the box at all, but rather a quantum state defined by a (superposition of) energies.

Comment: Would my edit to the question be a better question?

Comment: It'll take me a while to understand the wikipedia article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a particle with quantum behaviour, or classical behaviour? If it's classical you'll need to update it's position based on its initial velocity, and include bounces off walls, which are most easily modelled as elastic collisions which preserve the magnitude of its velocity at walls. If quantum, you will need to know its energy and the size of the box, from which you will get roughly a sine squared distribution, but the frequency of this sine will depend on the energy of the particle you're considering.

Comment: I'm looking for a quantum behaviour. Is this what you mean? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/idevbmktsf